# aync and await in monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, c#-5.0

Is it currently possible to use async and await in Monotouch 5.2.11. What c# 5.0 features are already available? Why does xamarin mobile require Async CTP for wp7 - that sort of tells me the library uses some async features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MonoTouch as of February 2013 does not currently ship with a C# 5.0 compiler.

We are planning on launching our Async support for the Evolve conference (xamarin.com/evolve) in April 2013.

## Old Response

As of May 19th, 2012, the answer was: we are waiting for Microsoft to officially release their compiler, which is a sign that they wont be making language or runtime changes.

Until then, it is not safe to ship a feature that might break.

The Xamarin.Mobile library is on a different schedule, it is currently in beta, so it can use some upcoming features.

Our plan is to release a C# 5-based MonoTouch shortly after Microsoft releases the official Visual Studio 2012 with C# 5

Comment: Just curious, now that the C# 5 compiler has gone RTM if monotouch/android will be getting async/await? :)

Comment: Any news on the time frame for supporting C# 5? It will be sooo nice to get the hands on async/await. Lot's of code to clean up. :)

Comment: How is the current status?

Comment: any progress on this matter?

Comment: You can get it in the alpha release channel (Xamarin.iOS 6.3)